# maven running test cases in separate JVM on windows

Tags: maven

We are using Maven project and all has been working fine until today.

`mvn package assembly:assembly` from command prompt in windows, Maven forks a separate process for running test cases in a separate window. This was not happening earlier and it is causing trouble. As the test case fails, and I don't know what failed. Please guide. I am using **maven 2.2.1**.Please suggest.

Comment: Take a look into your version control what has been changed?

Comment: +1 to khmarbaise.  Particularly, take a look at the maven-surefire-plugin and maven-failsafe-plugin versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```